# mysql: need records only if the date is there at least once each day, the date should be repeated for 4 days from the current datetime

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 6 columns: failure date, ipaddress, assettag, sid(primary key), rdl and error type. 
I need a table with columns as First failure, Recent(Last) failure, ipaddress, assettag, rdl
But the records are to be there only if the date is repeated for 4 days from the current datetime. Not even one single day to be missed. 
Ex: If today is 30th May, I need all the records whose failure date is there every single day--30th, 29th, 28th, 27th. If a record date is there only for two/three/one day(s)--it has to be ignored.

I can get First and Last failures using "min(date) and max(date)-group by ipaddress" but not able to get the records as per the condition--"failure (date) to be repeated for 4 days from current datetime"

```
    select min(date), max(date), ipaddress, assettag, rdl
 from flashinglist.response
  where ((DATE_FORMAT((date_sub(NOW(), interval 24 hour)), '%y-%m-%d')) in 
  (select group_concat((DATE_FORMAT(date,'%y-%m-%d')) separator ', ') 
from flashinglist.response group by ipaddress) 
       and (DATE_FORMAT((date_sub(NOW(), interval 48 hour)), '%y-%m-%d')) in 
        (select group_concat((DATE_FORMAT(date,'%y-%m-%d')) separator ', ') 
from flashinglist.response group by ipaddress)   
        and (DATE_FORMAT((date_sub(NOW(), interval 72 hour)), '%y-%m-%d')) in 
        (select group_concat((DATE_FORMAT(date,'%y-%m-%d')) separator ', ') 
from flashinglist.response group by ipaddress)  
        and (DATE_FORMAT((date_sub(NOW(), interval 96 hour)), '%y-%m-%d')) in 
        (select group_concat((DATE_FORMAT(date,'%y-%m-%d')) separator ', ') 
from flashinglist.response group by ipaddress) ) 
order by max(date) desc
```

The above query should work as I am concatenating all dates group by IP and checking through 'IN' condition, but it doesn't work, not able to figure out why. (used 'date_format' to find only date instead of timestamp)

Below is the schema and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE `response` (
  `date` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ipaddress` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `assettag` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `sid` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `rdl` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `errortype` int(2) NOT NULL)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO `response` (`date`, `ipaddress`, `assettag`, `sid`, `rdl`, `errortype`) VALUES
('2019-05-31 09:46:10.878', '123.34.45.67', 'fresh', 483, '13234', 1),
('2019-05-30 19:46:11.578', '123.34.45.67', 'fresh', 490, '13234', 1),
('2019-05-29 14:30:11.577', '123.34.45.67', 'fresh', 496, '13234', 1),
('2019-05-28 17:23:11.573', '123.34.45.67', 'fresh', 499, '13234', 1),
('2019-05-27 22:32:11.550', '123.34.45.67', 'fresh', 503, '13234', 1),
('2019-05-29 12:54:11.571', '457.673.768.24', 'store', 560, '9297', 1),
('2019-05-31 08:46:11.569', '457.673.768.24', 'store', 565, '9297', 1),
('2019-05-28 10:45:11.566', '457.673.768.24', 'store', 567, '9297', 1),
('2019-05-30 20:16:11.566', '457.673.768.24', 'store', 569, '9297', 1),
('2019-05-29 23:46:11.234', '140.232.546.74', 'sample', 580, '6076', 1),
('2019-05-31 09:26:11.562', '140.232.546.74', 'sample', 581, '6076', 1),
('2019-05-30 19:34:16.533', '140.232.546.74', 'sample', 583, '6076', 1);
COMMIT;
```

Please change values according to today's date and the last 4 days.
My output should return First failure, Recent(Last) failure, ipaddress, assettag, rdl-- with the above sample data, it has to show IP records: 123.34.45.67 and 457.673.768.24 with corresponding max and min dates with in the range of 1 to 96 hours (4 days) only. 
IP- 140.232.546.74 should not appear as it is the failure is not repeated for 4 days (28th date is missing). Hope this clears my question.

Comment: All those `date >` tests in the `WHERE` clause make no sense. Since you combine them with `AND`, you'll only match the last day.

Comment: Those `date` values are perfectly good `DATETIME(3)` values; please switch to that datatype so that the various date&time functions can readily be used.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I changed the schema earlier, varchar(50) to timestamp(3), it didn't work. As suggested I tried with datetime(3) too, but no luck :(

Comment: I have also tried as below by concatenating as strings (adding quotations to each string while group_concat) and kept the 'date' datatype the same as varchar(50): This is just subquery, I was not able to post the entire query in comments:
select max(date), ipaddress, assettag, rdl
 from flashinglist.response
  where ((concat('\'',(DATE_FORMAT((date_sub(NOW(), interval 96 hour)), '%y-%m-%d')),'\'')) in 
  (select group_concat((concat('\'',(DATE_FORMAT(date,'%y-%m-%d')),'\'')) separator ',') 
from flashinglist.response group by ipaddress))group by ipaddress
order by date desc;
No luck :(

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of different dates in the result, and test if this is the required number.

```
SELECT  min(date) AS mindate, max(date) AS maxdate, date, ipaddress, assettag, rdl 
FROM flashinglist.response 
  WHERE  date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour)
  AND date > date_sub(NOW(), interval 96 hour)
GROUP BY ipaddress
ORDER BY mindate DESC
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(date)) = DATE_SUB(maxdate, mindate) + 1
```

You also shouldn't have these lines:

```
  AND (date > date_sub(NOW(), interval 24 hour) )
  AND (date > date_sub(NOW(), interval 48 hour))
  AND (date > date_sub(NOW(), interval 72 hour))
```

since they will exclude rows that are more than 1 day old.

Comment: Hello, Great thanks for the response. Yes, I shouldn't have added those lines as they just check the condition individially but not if the date is present each day---repeated for 4 days. There is a syntax error with Date_sub function, so i modified it to datediff--- but I am not getting required output, still wondering how I can do this

Comment: What is the datatype of the `date` column? Is it `DATE` or `DATETIME`?

Comment: unfortunately it is neither of those two, it is varchar(50)

Comment: Does it contain the time, or just the date?

Comment: Add the table schema and sample data to the question.

Comment: I am trying another query though most of the code is redundant, but this too doesn't work, it doesn't show any records. Not able to figure the mistake here

Comment: Thank you for the responses, I have now added table schema and sample data.

Comment: You need to use `COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(date))` to ignore the times in the dates.

Comment: Thanks again for the response but the count query doesn't work as we don't have any fixed count to check the condition as the max and min dates always differ for each record. How about the below posted query, it seems correct as it satisfies the conditions but this is also not working, could you please check the below query once.